# How to create meshgrid with non-integer stepsize of list elements?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list-comprehension, numpy-slicing

I have 2 lists of x and y coordinate that are independently generated, with `a/h` amount of points between `0` and `a`.

```
x = np.linspace(0, a, a/h)
y = np.linspace(0, d, d/h)
```

when `a/h` is such that `0` increases to `a` in steps of integers i.e. `[0,1,2,..,a]`. It's nice because then the number of elements within the list can be used as indices. And as a result I can usually create a meshgrid such that a third list `V1` can be associated with it.

```
X, Y = plt.meshgrid(x, y)
def potential(V1):
    return V1[X, Y]
```

where `potential(V1)` is now `V1` corresponding to the meshgrid `[x, y]`. However I'm doing an assignment where I'm required to investigate how step-sizes affect my problem. As a result if I was to have a step-size of non-integers from `0` to `a` i.e. `[0, 0.5, 1,...,a]` Now I can't do what I did above since the indices are now non-integers. Raising the error

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

How can I fix this so that I don't rely on the value of the element itself as the index of the elements, so that if there was a step-size of `0.25` between `0` to `a` for a list `X` say i.e.

```
X = [0, 0.25, 0.75. 1.0] or x = np.linspace(0,1,4)
```

such that I can have

```
x[0] = 0 corresponds to V[0]
x[1] = 0.25 corresponds to V[1]
x[2] = 0.75 corresponds to V[2]
x[3] = 1 corresponds to V[3]
```

?